# KVM Spice connection to hardware GPU

Tags: kvm, vnc, spice

I have an asymmetric triple-head linux box.  It's hosting a Windows 10 VM with GPU passthrough, which I'd like to also have triple-head soft display on the Linux host.

Is there any way to use [Spice](https://www.spice-space.org/index.html) to expose my NVidia display to virt-viewer?

What I've tried:

- Manually switching the three monitors and having a second keyboard and mouse.  This got old very fast.
- Running tightvnc on the guest.  Couldn't figure out how to do cross-platform triple-head, and the performance wasn't great anyhow.
- Reinstalled Spice/QXL, and tried to use [Actual Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/) to mirror the GPU display onto the QXL display.  Couldn't make it go.

Answer (score 1):

Not technically an answer to my (slightly XY) question, but [Xfreerdp](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP) supports multi-monitor RDP quite nicely, and windows guests conveniently come with the server already installed.  Here's the commandline I needed to connect to a Windows 10 guest.

`xfreerdp +nego +sec-rdp +sec-tls +sec-nla /multimon /smart-sizing /v:guestname`

**Warnings:**

- it automatically goes to full-screen, and the only way out is with <kbd>ctrl-alt-enter</kbd> (or <kbd>r-ctrl</kbd> in v2).
- Obviously, for the host-to-guest connection to work, you have to be using bridged networking
- If your distro doesn't have v2 by default, jump through the hoops to get it.  If for nothing else, it's worth it to be able to tap <kbd>r-ctrl</kbd> in fullscreen in order to have your mouse and keyboard un-grabbed.  Lets you switch to a different workspace with no hassle.
- On Windows 7, you must have Ultimate or Enterprise.  Pro just gives you one large desktop spanning all your monitors.  Windows 10 appears to support multi-monitor RDP across the board.